# MultipartEntity addPart() method is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, multipartentity

I have used this before to send data to server in eclipse.
now I'm using the same thing in Android Studio but it's showing Exception.
in this line.

```
entity.addPart("product_id",new StringBody("Id",new StringBody("12")));
```

> I know, I should use volley but just curious why it is showing this
>   exception in Android Studio.

[image: Declaring method]

> Second image

[image]

> Showing this Exception

[image]

I have added everything on its place. 
**it is working in eclipse but not in android studio.**
is I'm doing something wrong here ?
Please help me with this.

Comment: Just use a try catch to wrap this line.It doesn't meaning it's wrong . Or you can use Alt+Enter on this line and close this tip.

Comment: yes it is worrking. thank you.